# Name cannot be found in current context

Tags: c#, methods, static

This is a pretty newbie question, but because I spent an afternoon trying and don't have any ideas left, I thought I post it here on Stackoverflow.

I'm building a program which pulls data from an open source API. I'm still a beginner, so I try to slowly tweaking the data so that it is displayed in the way I want it. However, I receive the error "The name 'MyOptionChainsInput' does not exist in the current context", and don't know how to solve it.

My **goal** is to make a list which gets populated in 'contract_details', in such a way that the list can be accessed in other methods (for example in Main(), which my properties have yet failed to do).

My code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Krs.Ats.IBNet;
using System.Threading;
using Krs.Ats.IBNet.Contracts;

namespace Krs.Ats.TestApp
{
public class Tester
{
    List<double> optionChainStrikes = new List<double>();
    List<string> optionChainExpiration = new List<string>();

    // properties
    public List<double> OptionChainStrikes
    {
        get
        {
            return optionChainStrikes;
        }
        set
        {
            value = optionChainStrikes;
        }
    }
    public List<string> OptionChainExpiration
    {
        get
        {
            return optionChainExpiration;
        }
        set
        {
            value = optionChainExpiration;
        }
    }

    public void MyOptionChainsInput(string expirationDate, double strike)
    {
        optionChainExpiration.Add(expirationDate);
        optionChainStrikes.Add(strike);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Commented code
        client.ContractDetails += contract_details; 
        // Because of this line, the method 'contract_details' (see below) has to be static.

        // Output the info of the option chains (This works and is an option, however, is it the best way?)
        Tester t = new Tester();
        t.MyOptionChainOutput(); 
    }

    static void contract_details(object sender, ContractDetailsEventArgs e) // This method has to be static.
    {
        //Tester t = new Tester(); // This creates on each call an new Tester instances, which also deletes the list.
        //t.MyOptionChainsInput(e.ContractDetails.Summary.Expiry, e.ContractDetails.Summary.Strike);
        MyOptionChainsInput(e.ContractDetails.Summary.Expiry, e.ContractDetails.Summary.Strike); // this doesn't work either
    }
}
}
```

At first glance, the solution is simple:

- Make the method 'contract_details' public, so it can access the 'MyOptionsChainInput' method, or
- Create a new instance of Tester in 'contract_details' and then access MyOptionsChainInput.

However, because of the constraints of the API interface which provides this option data, both options aren't possible. How can I solve this? Perhaps I even need to discard the class Tester and find another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, keep a static instance of tester around.

`// keep a static instance around
    static Tester tester = new Tester();
    static void contract_details(object sender, ContractDetailsEventArgs e) // This method has to be static.
    {
        // call the method on the static instance                
        tester.MyOptionChainsInput(e.ContractDetails.Summary.Expiry, e.ContractDetails.Summary.Strike); 
     }`

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've tried that, but because the API program calls on the 'contract_details' method for every new line of data, my Tester gets rewritten on each call, with result that the list never gets filled. :)

Comment: @Jura25 see my updated answer. Maybe a static instance of tester will work for you

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to just put the method in a class.
Look at your design, see what object should contain such a method, and put it there. The idea is to create an instance of an object that will register to the event.

Lets say class Blah will own the method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        // Commented code
        Blah temp = new Blah();
        client.ContractDetails += temp.contract_details; 
        // Because of this line, the method 'contract_details' (see below) has to be static.

        // Output the info of the option chains (This works and is an option, however, is it the best way?)
        Tester t = new Tester();
        t.MyOptionChainOutput(); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I don't think I understand you completely. I have put the method in a class (MyOptionsChainInput resided in the class Tester). The method 'contract_details' cannot be moved because the API uses that to supplement the ContractDetails() method. Or do I need an new class Blah besides the Tester class?